# What are necessary GeoExt dependencies?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js

Is use of  **OpenLayers-2.11** ,**GeoExt-1.1** and **ext-4.0.7-gpl** supported . I have only included ext-all.js in the script src. Should I include others too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that GeoExt does not work together with ExtJS 4 yet. 
You should use ExtJS 3.4.0 like GeoExt does in this [MapPanel example](http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/mappanel-div.html).

You also need to add the **ext-base.js** which you can see in the above mentioned example.

**Update:**

GeoExt does currently only work with ExtJS 3, but GeoExt is planing a [code sprint](http://blog.opengeo.org/2012/01/18/geoext-code-sprint-spring-2012/) that targets:

> developing GeoExt 2.0 to work with ExtJS 4

Comment: well EXTJS 4 doesn't have ext-base.js. I think same.

Comment: I did not know that. I have updated the answer because I just saw that GeoExt is planing a code sprint in the spring of 2012